# How can I disable these messages of dart on the VSCODE?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I want help to disable the messages of dart in de VScode as the example below:
[image: Messages of dart in the VSCODE].

Does anyone know?

Thanks in advance!!!

I tried to set any configuration in the dart extension, but I do not have success.

Comment: You don't want to know when you've strayed off the proper path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [errorLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.errorlens) extension causes this, you can delete it and it will disappear simply.

Comment: choosing this as right answer could help next person facing this trouble